# How can I suppress chrome-extension:// output from Web Inspector's console log?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, logging

I don't wish to disable my extensions – after all they're there for development purposes – but I want to disable their output from the console in Web Inspector. Is there a way to do this?

N.B. a very similar question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165857/how-to-remove-codes-generated-by-plugins-from-chrome-browser-developers-tool) on StackOverflow, but it seems that question and its answers are leaning towards *disabling* extensions, which is *not* what I want (since I obviously use them for development) – I simply want to **suppress** their output from the console.

[image]

Comment: 6 year later and they refuse to fix this issue, best you can do is set a filter each time you load devtools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to [@jarodjacob's answer](https://superuser.com/a/643934/1575165):

The "right-click and filter" method (right-clicking the white blank part of a console message and choosing "Hide Messages from X") adds a `-url:xxx` filter to the filter box, with the full URL of the log's source file.

However, the URL used in a `-url:xxx` filter doesn't have to be the full URL: **`-url:chrome-extension://` will hide *almost everything* that includes `chrome-extension://` in the source URL.** This will hide all regular logs from all extensions (warnings generated by the browser instead of being logged with the `console` object are not filtered).

The same behavior applies: the filter is kept until manually removed.

(Please note that this behavior was likely added after other answers were posted, which would mean it was not possible to do this at the time. Exact methods have also changed.)

Answer (score 17):

Firefox has [a way to change the console logging level for specific extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/console.html#Setting%20the%20Logging%20Level) from `about:config`.

Chrome doesn’t have this capability. Your options:

1. Filter out all messages from a particular source file by right-clicking the white (blank) part of console message line and choosing **Filter > Hide Messages from foo.js**. You can undo this filtering from the same menu later, if you wish. Chrome will remember to do this filtering for you until you disable it (even if you navigate somewhere else or restart Chrome).
2. Override one or more console methods. This approach only affects the current scripting context. Chrome extensions run in their own [isolated worlds](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) with their own window objects, global scopes, and console objects. If you can’t edit the source code of the extension, you’ll need to paste and run your console-altering scripts in each extension’s execution context, and your modifications will only be in effect until the page is unloaded. You can change the console’s effective execution context using the dropdown at the bottom of the console that says **`<page context>`**. Note that any frames or iframes in the page also have their own execution contexts, accessible using the frame dropdown (initially set to **`<top frame>`**).

Answer (score 2):

Just temporarily [disable the extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/niemebbfnfbjfojajlmnbiikmcpjkkja).

This will add a button to your browser and it will only require two clicks to toggle your extensions.

Comment: That's a nice tip (thanks!), however if you prefer to use the extensions while developing, it's awkward having to disable them just to get a clean console.

Comment: @hced: Another approach which might work is running in incognito mode and allow the extensions you need for developing in incognito. Yet another approach is creating a separate user profile for developing. From your screenshot it only appear to be two bad extensions, perhaps you can just disable those and/or find alternatives. In any case, a lot of options to try; and if you really want it, raise a feature request at Google Chrome and hopefully one day it'll be available for all developers...

Comment: This is not a solution.  I am on jsfiddle, programming at night.  I want my high-contrast extension to invert the colors, but I don't want to see its output.  There are other examples too.  There really should be a way to suppress just the console ouput....

Comment: @Jonah: Correct your extension to not output to the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, but there is an ongoing feature request for it (or, rather, for the same problem happening on the Network inspector tab). "Star" it to help make it happen :)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239401

Comment: Done deal, thanks for the tip! I starred the issue and also proposed an addition to it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239401#c10

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to hide extension logs in Chrome. just use console filter with following parameter

```
-source:other
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fOId.png)

Comment: Thank you Hoxz. Love getting answers 11 years after asking :-)

Comment: @Henrik For future generations :)

Comment: For me, this hides Chrome's source map failure logs, and not the extension logs.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes you can try to exclude messages by url. Like -url:chrome

Comment: @Hoxz Yes, as I stated in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1800201/1575165).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is loading the window **in cognito**, which by default ignores your extensions

Press **(cmd or ctrl) + shift + n** to load a private browsing session.